# Class variables behave differently (shared or not) based on their type

Tags: python

Number and lists behave differently when used as class variables: where numbers are not shared with instances while list variables are. (under the same conditions) can someone explain whats going on?

Ps: already asked this (less clearly explained) and it got flaired as a duplicate of a question about class variables in general. im asking why is there a difference between numbers and list class variables under the same conditions.

```
class test_class:
    number = 0
    list = [8]
    def addnum(self, num):
        self.number = num
    def addlist(self, list):
        self.list.append(list)
object = test_class()
object.addnum(5)
object.addlist(6)

print(test_class.number)
print(object.number)

print(test_class.list)
print(object.list)
```

this prints:

```
0
5         (number variable is not shared)
[8, 6]    (list was shared)
[8, 6]
```

expected:

```
0
5
[8]
[8, 6] (list gets appended without affecting the original)
```

Comment: There's no difference. If you had done `self.list = something`, you would have seen the same behavior as with the int.

Comment: Thats right, thanks!

Comment: **They are class variables instead of instance variables since you didn't define them through \__init__() method; this is pretty unusual and generally a bad idea.** Next, please don't call your methods  `addnum`,`addlist` when you really mean `set_num`, `append_list` because clearly they do two very different things; one is a setter and the other tries to append (an instance-specific argument, to a class variable - which is at best tortured, and at worst plain meaningless). (What is the meaning of the class variable `list = [8]`; seems meaningless to me?)

Comment: you're right, i didnt think the function names through, just made up for example's sake. for the list class variable its there to test out how it works thats all, better understanding of the mechanics is the best way to prevent issues later i guess (instead of just taking conventions like only using instance variables as you suggested)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class variables should be viewed as a kind of global variable: a place to store global state for the entire class (needed rarely), as well as a place to define shared constants (very common). If you want your instances to have data that varies from one instance to another, set them in the `__init__()` method, not at the class level.

As far as the discrepancy you observed, in one case you are assigning a value to an attribute and in the other case you are mutating a value already stored at the attribute. The core issue is the difference between **assignment** and **mutation**.

Comment: While this information is true, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @user2357112: Technically it supplies information that if pieced together could answer the question, but not in a way that any new user will understand. Needs a more prescriptive **"You're doing it wrong because your class initializes members with code at class-level; it doesn't have an `__init__()` which gets called on each instance"**. As proof why your code is wrong is that now all instances of the class share the same `.list` member: `object.list, obj2.list...`. This doesn't generally make sense, each instance should be 'insulated' from the others, so just declare an `__init__()` already.

Comment: well i know about instance variables, the question was about class variables on purpose, thanks everyone for your contributions!

Answer (score 0):

Doing an assignment looks like it solved it but i think there is more to it.
 When doing an assignment for self.list, an new and separate instance variable is created(as for the number), and it is the new reference for self.list, and when deleted, the class returns to its old list class variable. appending is shared since we are keeping the class variable and not creating an instance, this code explained it pretty well to me:

```
class test_class:
list = [8]
def addlist(self, liste):
    self.list= [liste]
def appendlist(self,new):
    self.list.append(new)
def delete(self):
    del self.list


object = test_class()

object.addlist(6) ## this creates a new and separate instance variable
print("------")
print(test_class.list)
print(object.list)


object.appendlist(2)  ## adds up to the instance variable
print("------")
print(test_class.list)
print(object.list)

object.delete()    ## deleting the instance var shows that the class var is still there
print("------")
print(test_class.list)
print(object.list)

object.appendlist(3)  ##class variable gets appended to, since we're not asking to create a new one
print("------")
print(test_class.list)
print(object.list)
```

this prints:

```
------
[8]
[6]
------
[8]
[6, 2]
------
[8]
[8]
------
[8, 3]
[8, 3]
```

Thanks for your answers!